# Rails 6 Production - Webpacker can't find styles in manifest.json

Tags: nginx, webpack-dev-server, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to run my rails 6 application in production, but facing internal server errors.

When I check the logs this is what I see:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find styles in /home/****/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.css": "/packs/css/application-8364df35.css",
  "application.js": "/packs/js/application-2789a226d9ddcf2c59d1.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-2789a226d9ddcf2c59d1.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "css": [
        "/packs/css/application-8364df35.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "/packs/js/application-2789a226d9ddcf2c59d1.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/js/application-2789a226d9ddcf2c59d1.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I check the server files everything is in there actually.

I am deploying via Capistrano and my server setup is nginx+puma.

Although everything works on localhost, I was not able to run server in production. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What ”_pack_tag” usages are in your layout/template/partials?

Comment: these are included on my application.html.erb
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'styles', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet ”pack” is called ”application” (not ”styles”).

Replace `stylesheet_pack_tag ’styles’` with  `stylesheet_pack_tag ’application’`.

Comment: perfect thanks. After that I had the problem of "No route matches [GET] /assets" with css files but setting this to true `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` solved it.
I will be looking for nginx solution